# Shorted pi zero w

Tags: pi-zero-w

So I was going to put a new case on my pi zero that I got for christmas but idiot Me left it on while trying to put a new on and accedently a mounting nut fell into the slot where the GPIO header whould have been and I instantly unplugged the pi from power.It is getting warm now but dosen´t show any video not even is the led indicator blinking.

Comment: It's probably trashed, sorry.

Comment: You have learned a $10 lesson the hard way.